# Добавить/убрать класс active, vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт, который добавляет/убирает класс `active` с `nav-link` в зависимости от `секции`. Но есть одно но, количество `секций` не равно количеству `nav-link`, поэтому необходимо, чтобы класс `active` убирался, если в данный момент неактивная `секция`. Сейчас же, если мы на неактивной `секции`, то класс `active` будет на `nav-link` предыдущей активной секции. Надеюсь понятно объяснил, если не поняли - спрашивайте. Так же snippet добавил, там показано как это сейчас работает.

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link');
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('.forJS');
  function changeLinkState() {
    let index = sections.length;

    while(--index && window.scrollY + 50 < sections[index].offsetTop) {}

    links.forEach((link) => link.classList.remove('active'));
    links[index].classList.add('active');
  }

changeLinkState();
window.addEventListener('scroll', changeLinkState);
```

```css
section{
height:100vh;
scroll-y:auto;
}
.nav-link.active{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
<header class="fixed-top">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navCustom">
    <div class="container">

          <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-center">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#main">Main</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#contacts">Contacts</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<section class="forJS text-center">Some info 1</section>
<section class="text-center">Some info 2</section>
<section class="text-center">Some info 3</section>
<section class="forJS text-center">Some info 4</section>
<section class="forJS text-center">Some info 5</section>
<section class="text-center">Some info 6</section>
<section class="text-center">Some info 7</section>
<section class="text-center">Some info 8</section>
<section class="text-center">Some info 9</section>
<section class="forJS text-center">Some info 10</section>
</body>
```

Comment: вместо класса, что секция влияет  на меню, лучше бы сделали data-атрибут, который показывает, к какому конкретно элементу меню эта секция привязана. ну или `id` выставть, ибо у меню есть `href` на секцию

Comment: если в данный момент неактивная секция - это как? forJS чередуется чтобы понять что секция сменилась?

Comment: @Sevastopol' вот оно то и не ясно у автора на 4 секции переход происходит ко второму меню, а как бы по логике должно было на второй

Comment: @Daniil Loban, почему переход должен быть на вторую? У меня 10 секций, а линки я сделал только для основных 4 и переходы соответственно к ним. Я не понимаю, что вы не можете понять))) Например у меня есть линк на портфолио и он в шапке светится активным даже если я будут находиться в секции с совершенно другим контентом.
А forJS показывает на какие секции есть линки в навигационной панели.

Comment: ага, понял ну да teran правильно написал лучше data-атрибут использовать а то логика не проглядывается но теперь ясно как - но не масштабируемо, в таком случае ответ уже дан внизу

Comment: А почему не масштабируемо? Можно ведь наращивать как секции так и линки, вроде без проблем должно работать. А с data-атрибутами это как? Добавляю вместо класса forJS data- атрибут и с JS обращаюсь уже к атрибуту, а не классу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никогда не используйте addEventListener на 'scroll' для контроля видимых областей. Для этого существует IntersectionObserver, на улице уже 2021 год.

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link');
const sections = [... document.querySelectorAll('.forJS')];

const callback = (entries) => {
  links.forEach((link) => link.classList.remove('active'));
  const elem = entries.find((entry) => entry.isIntersecting);
  if (elem) {
    const index = sections.findIndex((section) => section === elem.target);
    links[index].classList.add('active');
  }
}

let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, {
  rootMargin: '0px',
  threshold: 0.5
});

sections.forEach((section) => observer.observe(section));
```

```css
section {
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-y: auto;
}
.nav-link.active{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
<header class="fixed-top">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navCustom">
    <div class="container">

          <ul class="navbar-nav justify-content-center">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#main">Main</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#contacts">Contacts</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>

<section class="forJS text-center">Some info 1</section>
<section class="forJS text-center">Some info 2</section>
<section class="forJS text-center">Some info 3</section>
<section class="text-center">Some info 4</section>
<section class="text-center">Some info 5</section>
<section class="text-center">Some info 6</section>
<section class="text-center">Some info 7</section>
<section class="text-center">Some info 8</section>
<section class="text-center">Some info 9</section>
<section class="forJS text-center">Some info 10</section>
</body>
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает! Я не так давно JS использовать начал, всех нюансов пока не знаю.